# Combinatorial arguments

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone guide me through logic for this combinatorial proof

Let $c_n$ denote the number of triangulations of a
regular $(n + 2)$-gon by non-intersecting diagonals.

[image]

Comment: what is $c_n$ ? is there a problem that defines $c_n$?

Comment: editted * @Kf-Sansoo

Comment: what is the "number of triangulations of a regular ..." ? can you provide some example ? how much is $c_1,c_2$?

Comment: It's a bit complex, hence the confusion on my end. Basically what it means is how many triangles you can create within a polygon of (n+2) sides

Comment: this is a well know succession, but i dont remeber the name...

Comment: ok i got it, catalan numbers, check for wikipedia!

Comment: This was already posted yesterday and it's related to Catalan numbers:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755966/catalan-numbers-and-triangulation/1757041#1757041